# DB2: How do I remove AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: sql, db2, auto-increment

How do I remove AUTO_INCREMENT of a column in DB2?

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER my_id
```

but no luck. What is the correct SQL statement?

Comment: do you mean that a column value is generated and the value increments for each new row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [modify a column definition of a DB2 table](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html) and remove the generation of values:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycol DROP GENERATED;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Auto_increment by using the following

> ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name DROP **IDENTITY**;